# Windows phone 8 app cancels service query (HttpClient) that takes longer than a minute

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, httprequest, dotnet-httpclient

I have a problem with my WP8 App, if the service query takes longer than one minute (please download the sample from following link). It includes a WPF and WP8 project. The HttpClient is in portable class library. Please run these projects and see the difference.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6DAC64582B6A66C3!43687&authkey=!AE0-_gF21zojzBw&ithint=file%2czip

Why I get this 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' (Response status code does not indicate success: 404) on WP8 after one minute (WPF App runs successful)?

Thank for your help!

Comment: Have you tried increasing the HTTPClient Timeout value?

Comment: Yes. The default value is 100 seconds https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx When I set the value to 30 seconds, I get the TaskCanceledException after this time. Increase the value nothing helps...

Comment: There is also a Stream.ReadTimeout although I'm not sure how you would set that. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx